Ruby on Rails - Caracal gem
Trying to generate a three-column list of Operators and their addresses. Think mailing labels. I gather that I just need a better split somewhere but I can't see it. Help appreciated.
def create
  stored_procedure = "EXEC dbo.GetDocumentData_DoStuff"

begin
  # Retrieve data from the stored procedure
  result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(stored_procedure).first
  operator_list = result['operatorList'] || result['opList']

  # Ensure operator_list is not nil
  if operator_list.nil?
    flash[:error] = "No data available to generate the document."
    redirect_to request.referrer and return
  end

  # Prepare data for columns
  addresses = operator_list.split(" | ")

  # Create a new Document with Caracal
  Caracal::Document.save 'report.docx' do |docx|
    docx.style do
      id 'Normal'
      name 'Tahoma'
      font 'Tahoma'
      size 20 # Setting size in half-points (20 half-points = 10 points)
    end

    docx.h1 'Operator List Report'
    docx.h3 "Generated on #{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"

    # Add Operator List with address in three columns
    addresses.each_slice(3) do |row|
      docx.table([row]) do
        row.each do |address|
          address.split(" /n ").each do |line|
            docx.p line, font: 'Tahoma', size: 18, align: :left
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # Send the file to the user
  send_file 'report.docx', type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', filename: 'report.docx'
rescue => e
  flash[:error] = "There was an error generating the document: #{e.message}"
  redirect_to request.referrer
end

end
So good news, the SQL works and the docx generates. But, I just cannot for the life of me to get the strings/records to split where I want them to and I'll wind up with multiple Operators in a single table cell or the custom separator string to show up literal.
The SQL select with separators for reference:
INSERT INTO #operatorTable (FormattedAddress)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONCAT_WS(' /n ',
        CONCAT(rc.CONAME, ' (', rc.CONO, ')'),
        NULLIF(rc.ADDR1, ''),
        NULLIF(rc.ADDR2, ''),
        RTRIM(CONCAT(
            NULLIF(rc.CITY, ''), 
            CASE 
                WHEN rc.CITY <> '' AND rc.STATE <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' 
            END,
            NULLIF(rc.STATE, ''), 
            ' ', 
            CASE 
                WHEN NULLIF(rc.ZIP2, '') IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(NULLIF(rc.ZIP1, ''), '-', NULLIF(rc.ZIP2, ''))
                ELSE NULLIF(rc.ZIP1, '')
            END
        )),
        ' | '
    )

Closest I can get is something like this:


docx.table([row]) is generating the rows in the table using the raw strings provided, which is why you see the new line breaks in the table cells.
docx.p is printing the values to the document (not the table), which is why the line breaks are correct but it is outside of the table.
It appears that what you want to do is use a Caracal::Core::Models::TableCellModel. As stated in the docs:

If your table contains more complex data (multiple paragraphs, images, lists, etc.), you will probably want to instantiate your TableCellModel instances directly

Please try this instead:(untested)
Caracal::Document.save 'report.docx' do |docx|
  docx.style do
    id 'Normal'
    name 'Tahoma'
    font 'Tahoma'
    size 20 # Setting size in half-points (20 half-points = 10 points)
  end

  docx.h1 'Operator List Report'
  docx.h3 "Generated on #{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"

  # construct all the cells first 
  cells = addresses.each do |address| 
    Caracal::Core::Models::TableCellModel.new do 
      address.each_line(chomp: true) do |line| 
        p line.strip
      end 
    end 
  end 
  # add all the rows to the table at once
  docx.table([cells.each_slice(3).to_a])
end

You will likely have to handle the table formatting to some extent as well as possibly address the fact that your "address" strings appear to have a trailing new line character.
